# (Django) HTML: Table columns are displaying vertically

Tags: html, django, html-table

I'm currently trying to display a bunch of Information of a model inside the template.

Therefore I've been creating a table to show all of the information horizontally for every "previous game" in the database:

```
<table style="height: 100%">
     {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
            <tr>
                <th> {{ previous_game.name }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <img id="Videogame_Picture" src="{{ previous_game.image.url }}"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ previous_game.date }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.min_req %} "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.rec_req %} " ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> PC Rig {{ previous_game.config }}</td>
            </tr>
       {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

It shall look like this:

[image: How_it_should_look]

But currently all the Table columns are displaying vertically underneath instead of horizontally next to each previous game and I can't figure out why.

Can you help me out here?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I got a solution:

Since I created a Row for every Information of the "previous game" - Object, in every loop, I needed to put the loop inside the Row, for being able to only create the Row once.

Now it looks like this:

```
<table style="height: 150px; border: 1px solid black; width: 600px">

                <tr>
                    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
                         <th> {{ previous_game.name }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
                        <td> <img id="Videogame_Picture" src="{{ previous_game.image.url }}"> </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
                        <td> {{ previous_game.date }} </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
                        <td style="display: inline"> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.min_req %} "></td>
                        <td style="display: inline"> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.rec_req %} " ></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
                        <td> PC Rig {{ previous_game.config }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
        </table>
```

It doesn't feel like the cleanest solution tbh, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would have all my headers in the first row and then start looping through my games with a row per game and cells (td) for each game attribute:

```
<table style="height: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th> previous game name </th>
        <th> image </th>
        <th> previous game date </th>
        <th> previous game result 1 </th>
        <th> previous game result 2 </th>
        <th> PC Rig </th>
    </tr>
    {% for previous_game in previous_games %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ previous_game.name }} </td>
        <td> <img id="Videogame_Picture" src="{{ previous_game.image.url }}"> </td>
        <td> {{ previous_game.date }} </td>
        <td> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.min_req %} "> </td>
        <td> {% load static %} <img id= "Result_Icon" src="{% static previous_game.rec_req %} " ></td>
        <td>{{ previous_game.config }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for Answering! In this case i would got a Table with all the Table data Horizontally next to each other and every "previous game" underneath each other. It's a way, but I want to have the previous games Horizontally next to each other and all the Table data Vertically underneath. :')

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of what you are after, perhaps mock up a spreadsheet image. I can't visualise what you are going for.

Comment: of course! Just give me a second, I edit the question

Comment: I added it :)! Everything is currently in one column underneath everything. But it should actually look like this picture up there.. Just ONE column for every "previous game", ONE row for the header and all the Table Data underneath each other, but the Games are next to each other

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are hoping for. You want to loop through your previous films to create columns but my understanding is that tables are created in rows. You could change the data structure that you are passing to the template, so for example each row element has access to a fixed number of previous games so you can target prev_game_1.name or prev_game_1.date

Comment: I already solved it (see my Answer :) ) but thank you for you input and mental support!